# Order independent weighted random selection

Tags: algorithm, math, random, probability

Say I have a pool of items to be randomly selected.

And I use a simple weighted selection algorithm to do so:

1. Calculate item weight sum;
2. Pick a random number between 0 and weight sum;
3. Iterate over items, and decrease by item weight, select item when <0

And in the meantime, a constraint propagation algorithm updates the pool of available items.

- For example, say we have a N by N grid, each cell can select a number.
- The selection is done through weighted selection, using algorithm above.
- Once a cell selects its number, it also limits neighbouring cells' available numbers using some rules.

**And here is my problem:**

- Say cell A and B are neighbours.
- Say initially, both of them can select from a pool of numbers.
- But once A or B is determined, the other cell will have less number to choose from.
- Thus, even for the same random number input, the weighted selection can still yield different result (because weight sum and item probability has changed).
- So the selection process is not order-independent, even if the random number is order-independent.

How can we ensure outcome of A and B are random and independent, while still being able to propagate constraints? (Is it even possible in my case?)

**Update:**

The algorithm I am basing my idea on is [WaveFunctionCollapse](https://github.com/mxgmn/WaveFunctionCollapse#algorithm), due to the way it works, we cannot guarantee the order of observation because it always pick the cell with least entropy.

I find my [initial constraint](https://github.com/mxgmn/WaveFunctionCollapse#constrained-synthesis) changes the outcome in unpredictable ways because available entropy is now different, so the observation order changes, and observation result for the same cell also changes.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is to assign a separate weight table for each cell.  In this case, the random selection occurs pass-by-pass, where in each pass, you choose a random number for each cell and then remove the chosen number from consideration on each cell.  (Think how the cells in Conway's Game of Life are updated.)  However, this may take a lot of memory, especially if there are many items to choose from or the size of the grid is large.  Please try this idea; if it's not fast enough, please measure to find where the bottlenecks may be, and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Thx, I realize I essentially need to figure out a new way to do weighted random selection. The way you describe is do-able. However my algorithm do rely on the order of observation to achieve certain result (we always *observe* the cell with least entropy). It's a form of [WFC](https://github.com/mxgmn/WaveFunctionCollapse#algorithm). I am trying to modify it so that setting [initial constraint](https://github.com/mxgmn/WaveFunctionCollapse#constrained-synthesis) doesn't alter result. I will update my post.